# SQL Server : Combination of 2 columns to be maintained Across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:
First table is as follows: Table1

SomeID      Org
1   Org1
2   Org2
3   Org3

And second is as follows: Table2
LatestSomeID    Org

The entry for SomeID and Org will be first added to table 1, and then the same will be updated in the table2
I want that in table 2, the combination of SomeID and Org should be maintained 
i. e. if someone tries to enter **'1' and 'Org2' in Table2**, it should raise error.

I understand that I need to write a Before Insert /Update trigger on Table 2, but not sure how.
Please help. Also please confirm that a trigger is essential, or can we do with a Constraint alone?

Comment: What about just UNIQUE  (SomeID ,Org) at TABLE1 and foreign key at TABLE2  (LatestSomeID, Org) references TABLE1(SomeID ,Org)

Comment: Thanks, that helped in resolving the issue!